# Why is this code working in a different way than expected? I think its working right, is it?

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

Here is what I am supposed to do.

[image]

Here is what I did.(on codeblocks IDE with minGW compiler)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class person

{
private:
string name;
int age;
double height;
double weight;
public:
void set_private_members(string n, int a, double h, double w)
{
    name = n;
    age = a;
    weight = h;
    height = w;
}
void print_private_members()
{
    cout <<"The name of person is:- "<<name<<"\n The age of person is:- "  <<age<<"\n The weight of person is:- "<<weight;
    cout <<"\n The height of person is:- "<<height<<endl;
}
};

void modify_person(person);

int main()

{
person p;
p.set_private_members("Ayush",19,165.7,47.2);
cout <<"We are in main function right now \n";
p.print_private_members();
modify_person(p);
cout <<"We are now back in main function \n The values of object passed  to modify_person function are as \n";
p.print_private_members();

return 0;
}

void modify_person(person z)
{
cout <<"We are in modify_person function \n Modifying person details... \n";
z.set_private_members("Priyanshi",15,159.1,50.6);
cout <<"The details are now as:- \n";
z.print_private_members();
}
```

Here is the output to this code

[image]

however the expected output is to have priyanshi details in the class object when print_private_members function is called in main() for the last time.

Who is wrong? Me or they? I think if I call modify_person by reference then the expected should come.

Comment: "I think if I call modify_person by reference then the expected should come." Yes it would, if you
modified `p` by *reference* instead of by *value*: `void modify_person(person z)` -> `void modify_person(person & z)`

Comment: @MikeKinghan but I am not supposed to do that. Please read what I have to do from the first picture.Step 23 to Step 30.

Comment: In that case, why do you believe you are calling `modify_person` *by reference*?
A function cannot modify an object that is passed by value. There is nothing more
basic than that in C++. The exercise wants you to show that you understand that
`modify_person` cannot modify a `person` unless the `persion` is passed *by reference*.

Comment: hmm.. okay thanks, means I did evrything right.

Comment: No. You are passing a `person` to `modify_person` by *value*, not by
*reference*, which is why it does not modify the `person` that you pass
and fails to satisfy the requirements of the exercise.

Comment: do I have to pass it by reference ? Its not written anywhere. Anyways, my poor english. Extremely sorry if that's the case.